# Trying to disable the metrics logging in Ignite but failed

Tags: ignite

Found that the Ignite Metrics logging is a bit excessive so decided to disabled it.
[image]

As indicated in the screenshot, it should be done by setting setMetricsLogFrequency to 0.
However, it does not work. Below is my code for creating IgniteConfiguration. Note that Ignite is created with client mode.

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0); // Trying to disabled it!
cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("IgnitePod");
cfg.setClientMode(true);
cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true);
// Ignite persistence configuration.
DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

Ignite ignite =  Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a different Ignite instance. Your one is called "IgnitePod" but this one is "CacheManager_0". You need to adjust its config, too.